# Rich Snippet AggregateRating on type Place

Tags: microdata, schema.org

According to schema.org [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place) should support `AggregateRating`.

But when I use this snippet:

```
<div class="row-fluid rating-summary" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">         
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">    
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span>
    <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>                
    <span itemprop="ratingCount"21</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Googles Rich Snippet tester](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) won't display the rating until I exchange `Place` with `Product`. That’s of course wrong.

I can solve this by using

```
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"
```

on the `body` but I would really like to know what’s the best way to integrate `Rating` for Rental Properties.

Comment: I don't see the point. When I validate your snippet using Google or Yandex (http://webmaster.yandex.ru/microtest.xml) Tools, it works pretty well. (itemType = http://schema.org/Place
aggregaterating
itemType = http://schema.org/AggregateRating
ratingvalue = 4.5
bestrating = 5
ratingcount = 21)

Comment: Yeah, but replace Place with Product and you will see that Google will display the rating stars like in an actual search list.

Comment: Stars, got you. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try smth like this

```
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">  
     <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">    
        Avg. Rating:
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">9</span> 
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10"/>   
        <span itemprop="ratingCount">4</span> Reviews 
     </div>

     <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
        <a itemprop="url" href="wells-fargo-center.html">
        Wells Fargo Center
        </a>
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
          <span itemprop="addressLocality">Philadelphia</span>,
          <span itemprop="addressRegion">PA</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you see the idea is to put Place inside Review. Google gives stars for that.
[image]

Not so nice as for me but works.